# Store a Value in a Property with Ant or Phing

Tags: ant, properties, phing

With Ant or Phing, I need to load a file's contents into a property, run a regular expression on the value of that property, and then store the result of that regular expression in another property. What's the best way to do this?

I can load the file into a property easily (with Phing) like so:

```
<loadfile file="myfile.txt" property="my.file" />
```

And I know how to update the file, but I can't seem to figure out how to run a regex on that property, and store the result in a new property for future use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### Update

I've been tinkering with it, and this will work. Let me know if there's a streamlined way though! The code below loads a file into a property, then reduces it to only the line that contains the `title` tag. And then, it runs a regular expression on that line, and stores the contents of that tag in my.prop.

```
<loadfile file="../index.html" property="my.prop">
  <filterchain>
     <linecontainsregexp>
        <regexp pattern="&lt;title>" />
    </linecontainsregexp>

    <replaceregexp>
        <regexp pattern="[\s\S]+<title>(.+?)</title>" replace="$1" />
    </replaceregexp>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

#### Update 2

Actually, I ended up using an `adhoc` task to create my own. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can run an arbitrary command from an ant target like this:

```
<exec executable="bash">
   <arg line="script.sh"/>
</exec>
```

You can for example store the result of the regexp in a tmp file and then load it into another property the same way as the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

In Phing you could process the content of the property where you loaded the file using the "php" task. See: http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#PhpEvalTask